# Filter first date per year with several columns

Tags: r

Been looking for a while without finding answers so try here:

I have a group of data in a column where the first observation of an animal is listed.
**2022-05-03. 2022-05-01. 2022-04-23, 2021-05-04, 2021-02-31, 2020-01-30, 2020-05-20** and so on.

I am looking for finding the first observation per year using the filter() function. How is that supposed to like, is the lubridate function something to apply?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example:  [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Consider sth like `x <- c('2022-05-03', '2022-05-01', '2022-04-23', '2021-05-04', '2021-02-31', '2020-01-30', '2020-05-20'); x[which.min(as.Date(x))]`

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf. If my data is named "Animal_data" and the column "date". How would that code look like? I'm a beginner so sorry if I don't mind asking.

Comment: @JosephCarthof I elaborate on that in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72986330/6574038).

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df = tibble(date = as.Date(c("2022-05-03", "2022-05-01", "2022-04-23", "2021-05-04", "2021-02-28", "2020-01-30", "2020-05-20")))
```

Then, to get the first date by year:

```
df %>% mutate(year = year(date)) %>% arrange(date) %>% group_by(year) %>% slice(1)
```

Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks! If my data is namned "Animal_data" and the column with dates "date". How would that look like?

Comment: If you use the `animal_data` dataframe defined by @jay.sf, you can use the `dplyr` code as follow:
`animal_data %>% mutate(year = year(date)) %>% arrange(date) %>% group_by(year, animals) %>% slice(1) %>%ungroup() %>% select(-year)
`

Answer (score 0):

I show you some ways  First of all, use `"Date"` format for dates!

```
animal_data <- transform(animal_data, date=as.Date(date))
```

Here an option using `aggregate` with formula interface, aggregating at animal name and 1-4 `substr`ings of the date, i.e. the year,

```
aggregate(date ~ animals + substr(date, 1, 4), animal_data, min)
#   animals substr(date, 1, 4)       date
# 1 Gorilla               2020 2020-07-05
# 2  Rhebok               2020 2020-02-22
# 3  Vicuna               2020 2020-06-23
# 4 Gorilla               2021 2021-01-11
# 5  Rhebok               2021 2021-03-10
# 6  Vicuna               2021 2021-05-24
# 7 Gorilla               2022 2022-05-03
# 8  Rhebok               2022 2022-04-29
```

or with list notation, where we are most flexible regarding the column names of the result.

```
with(animal_data, aggregate(list(date=date), list(animals=animals, year=substr(date, 1, 4)), min))
#   animals year       date
# 1 Gorilla 2020 2020-07-05
# 2  Rhebok 2020 2020-02-22
# 3  Vicuna 2020 2020-06-23
# 4 Gorilla 2021 2021-01-11
# 5  Rhebok 2021 2021-03-10
# 6  Vicuna 2021 2021-05-24
# 7 Gorilla 2022 2022-05-03
# 8  Rhebok 2022 2022-04-29
```

Another way is using `ave` in `subset`. `subset` expects a logical condition. `ave` internally splits the date at animal then at the year and applies `which.max` on this subset. We compare the output of `ave`—the first obs of the animal in that year—with the date and in this way create the logical subset.

```
subset(animal_data, ave(date, animals, substr(date, 1, 4), FUN=\(x) x[which.min(x)]) == date)
#    animals       date
# 1   Rhebok 2020-02-22
# 2   Vicuna 2020-06-23
# 3  Gorilla 2020-07-05
# 12 Gorilla 2021-01-11
# 13  Rhebok 2021-03-10
# 14  Vicuna 2021-05-24
# 19  Rhebok 2022-04-29
# 20 Gorilla 2022-05-03
```

Now you probably have a few options to choose from.

---

*Data:*

```
animal_data <- structure(list(animals = c("Rhebok", "Vicuna", "Gorilla", "Rhebok", 
"Rhebok", "Gorilla", "Rhebok", "Vicuna", "Vicuna", "Gorilla", 
"Vicuna", "Gorilla", "Rhebok", "Vicuna", "Rhebok", "Rhebok", 
"Rhebok", "Vicuna", "Rhebok", "Gorilla"), date = structure(c(18314, 
18436, 18448, 18487, 18502, 18516, 18549, 18582, 18588, 18589, 
18604, 18638, 18696, 18771, 18806, 18807, 18911, 18938, 19111, 
19115), class = "Date")), row.names = c(8L, 15L, 9L, 18L, 3L, 
20L, 4L, 14L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 17L, 11L, 6L, 19L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 12L, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```